# SED Search and Replace on Linux

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, perl, replace

I want to change the value from 1521 to 1525 in `FROM_HOST only` in file `gexhosts.cat`:

```
FROM_HOST   db201521
TO_HOST     db201521
```

Is there a way to do that or some work around?

I would really prefer if we could use `sed` as I am using `sed` for many other activities of mine.

Comment: Nope Sir. It definitely is similar, But not exactly what i was looking for. In fact, That was the very first page i looked into when i seeked google's help. Thanks again.

Comment: It's a duplicate because it's the same problem with the same solution.  The fact that your particular strings (1521 and 1525) aren't mentioned is irrelevant, it's still a simple search and replace question.  The linked-to duplicate provides answers for most of the basic search-and-replace queries.  Read, understand, and extrapolate to your exact needs.   This site prefers answers that teach rather than answers that spoon-feed.

Comment: Understood. I agree with you on the spoon-fed part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed '/^FROM_HOST/ s/1521$/1525/' gexhosts.cat
```

To edit the file in place:

```
sed -i.bak '/^FROM_HOST/ s/1521$/1525/' gexhosts.cat
```

The original file will be backed up as `gexhosts.cat.bak` and the modified file will be `gexhosts.cat`.

If you don't want to keep a back up:

```
sed -i '/^FROM_HOST/ s/1521$/1525/' gexhosts.cat
```

Comment: Heemayl, You're a miracle worker. You know that ?? Thanks much for the solution. Now i am on my way to respond to Eric 'cos his solution was right too.

Comment: @AravindhanK Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like:

```
sed 's/\(FROM_HOST.*\)1521/\11525/' gexhosts.cat
```

Comment: Hello Eric. It worked! I am shouting lotsa YAYs in my desk here. Thanks for making my life easier.